# Replaced water filter now very low water pressure

Tags: refrigerator, water-pressure

Had very strong water pressure through water dispenser. Then replaced water filter and now very, very slow water.  Did all the things everyone has suggested to no effect.  Found that by pulling the bottom of the filter towards the front of the refrigerator water pressure increased.  Shouldn't have to do that and may lead to breaking the water filter off but doesn't seem like there is any other solution.  I will tape a wedge of some type to the lower portion of the filter so that it pushes against the inside rear wall of the refrigerator and pushes the bottom of the filter towards the front of the refrigerator.

Comment: are the old one and the new one exactly the same size, down to millimeters?

Comment: Different brands of filters can also make a difference.  I bought cheap filters specifically because they had a better flow rate than the better quality manufacturer filters.